# How to do text markers with Google Maps API

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

Did anybody know how to do the text markers and custom-styled baloons ?
Like on the site http://nano.aviasales.ru/map

Comment: Explore the code behind that site and give it a try. If you are having problems after that, update this question with the code that isn't working and a specific question about your problem. Until then, this isn't really a programming question.

Comment: I explored the code before I asked the question.

Comment: And don't know how they do that. Maybe they used some non documented features or some JS tricks. Also JS code is minimized and hard to explore.
Probably you have any ideas about how this text markers was created.

Comment: Yes, they have run their JavaScript libraries through a compiler and that will make it very hard to decipher their code. But that isn't a programming problem you are having with _your_ code. I'm not giving you a hard time, but questions should be about a problem you are having in your code and usually include a code sample. Questions that just give a link to another site and ask, "How did they do that?" aren't a good fit here. I made similar mistakes when I first joined StackOverflow. Please take a look at the [FAQ section on Questions](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#questions).

Comment: Sean Mickey, thanks for your understanding. I'll take your advice.